# Determine if a mathematical statement always holds

Tags: simplifying-expressions, logic

I know that $\exists a,a\in\mathbb{Z}\land a+1>a$ is always true, and $\forall a,a\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow a+1>a$ is also always true; I try to use function `FullSimplify` to let *Mathematica* determine if this is correct, the first one simplifies to `True`, but the second one didn't, I think this sometimes happens when the statement and the negation of it are both satisfiable, however it says the negation of second statement is always `False`, which implies the original statement is always `True`, but why it didn't evaluate like that ?

Here is the code:

```
i = Exists[a, And[Element[a, Integers], a + 1 > a]]
```

$\exists a,a\in\mathbb{Z}\land a+1>a$

```
FullSimplify[i]

   True

ii = ForAll[a, Implies[Element[a, Integers], a + 1 > a]]
```

$\forall a,a\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow a+1>a$

```
FullSimplify[ii]
```

$\forall a,a\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow a+1>a$

**(Q: Why this didn't evaluate as True ?)**

```
FullSimplify[Not[ii]]

   False
```

Comment: The (seemingly ridiculous) solution: `Resolve[ForAll[a, Implies[Element[a, Integers], a + 1 > a]], Reals]`

Comment: @J.M. Resolve seems works better for this, thanks.